# Active window-title

Tags: c#, user32

I want to get the string of the title of the currently active window in a C# console application.

My below code does just that. However, it only works when I debug the code slowly line by line. When I just hit run, the `while` seems to enter an infinite loop. Without the `while` loop, however, no window title is found (and hence not written to the console) in the first place.

What's wrong? And how to fix it?

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, System.Text.StringBuilder text, int count);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();
        const int nChars = 256;
        System.Text.StringBuilder Buff = new System.Text.StringBuilder(nChars);
        while (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) <= 0)
        {
            // Wait until GetWindowText returns a positive value
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Buff.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a loop there? Call `GetWindowTextLength()` to size the buffer, then call `GetWindowText()` to get the text

Comment: @Jimi I explained the loop. Without it I just got an empty string in the first place, as if the program run too quickly. So I wait while GetWindowText is nothing.

Comment: Kind of unclear what you really want - code as shown grabs semi-random window handle and try to get title out of it forever... which is quite unlikely to change... Note that if you are running from console/terminal focus will be on that window.... and focus during non-remote debugging is complete mess.

Comment: Yep, but why a loop? Do you mean you are *waiting* for a window other than the window of your Console app to become the foreground  window? `IntPtr handle` is always the same, though. Can you explain what this is for? -- If you need to know when a Window becomes the Foreground Window, you can use `SetWinEventHook()` (`EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND`)

Comment: Try putting a `Thread.Sleep(100)` call in your `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a loop? If you want to continuously check the active window title, you want to move the `IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();` to the loop too, and also I guess you need to slow it down a little bit. Anyway, this works fine for me:

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, System.Text.StringBuilder text, int count);
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {        
        // You may want to add a circuit breaker here, e.g. when a key is storked
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetActiveWindowTitle());
            Thread.Sleep(300);
        }        
    }

    public static string GetActiveWindowTitle()
    {
        const int nChars = 256;
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(nChars);
        IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();        

        return GetWindowText(handle, buffer, nChars) > 0 ? buffer.ToString() : string. Empty;
    }
}
```

p.s. This is a very interesting related project: https://github.com/dotnet/pinvoke